# Removing horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

In the jsfiddle below there are two buttons that open a menu div on the left or right side of the screen.

As the menus are opened, the rest of the site (I used the html div) moves with them.

My problem is that when the left menu is opened, the html div becomes scrollable left and right, whereas it doesn't when the right menu is opened.

I'm not sure why this is, but I want to remove the left-to-right scroll if possible, without adding `overflow:hidden` because that way I would also lose the ability to scroll up and down.

https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/62/

My code is the  following:

**HTML:**

```
<header class="header">
  <span id="button-one"></span>
  <span id="button-two"></span>
  <div class="push-menu-one"></div>
  <div class="push-menu-two"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>

<div class="content"></div>

<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:pink;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1); 
}

body {
  min-height:100%;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 

  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;

  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height:70px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:white;
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;

  width:85%;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.footer {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;

  height: auto;
  width: 100%;      
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
 }

/* PUSH MENUS */

#button-one {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:green;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#button-two {
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:orange;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.push-menu-one {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:-295px;
  width:295px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:wheat;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
}

.push-menu-two {
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   right:-295px;
   width:295px;
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:darkred;
   -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
   transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
}

.overlay {
   position:fixed;
   z-index:9;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:0px;
   height:0px;
   background-color:#000000;
   opacity:0;

   transition: opacity 1s, width 0s ease 1s, height 0s ease 1s;
 }

.overlay.open-right,
.overlay.open-left {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   opacity:0.4;

   transition: opacity 1s;
}
/* TOGGLE CLASSES */

html.open-left {
  left:295px;
}

.push-menu-one.open-left {
  left:0;
}

html.open-right {
  left:-295px;
}

.push-menu-two.open-right {
  right:0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('#button-one').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one').toggleClass('open-left');

 });

 $('#button-two').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-two').toggleClass('open-right');

});

$('.overlay').click(function() {
        $('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one, .push-menu-two').removeClass('open-left');

$('html, .overlay, .push-menu-one, .push-menu-two').removeClass('open-right');

});

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

*From the comments:*

> Do you know why the scroll only affected the html/body when the left menu opened? Seems strange that it didn't do the same on the right.

Think about the flow of content.

In left-to-right language mode, content overflows to the right. It does not overflow to the left.

Hence, scrolling (a function of `overflow` in CSS) doesn't apply to the left because there is no overflow.

In right-to-left languages, the reverse is true.

You can switch your content to RTL mode – either with the CSS `direction` property or the HTML `dir` attribute – to enable RTL scroll in LTR languages (but it's a hack and can get messy).

*From the spec:*

> [**11.1.1 Overflow: the `overflow`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#overflow)
>
> This property specifies whether content of a block container element
>   is clipped when it overflows the element's box.

Again, in LTR reading/writing mode, content does not overflow to the left.

In general, it's common to invoke the `overflow` property for scrolling to the left of the viewport, only because `overflow` is commonly associated with scroll bars. But in reality such a request is for specialized scrolling, having nothing to do with `overflow`. Consider JS/jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this worked. Do you know why the scroll only affected the html/body when the left menu opened? Seems strange that it didn't do the same on the right.

Comment: @Jack1991 the reason that the horizontal scroll bar appeared only on the left menu, is because opening the left menu pushed the page content off the page.  The page reads from left to right, so when you push out of the right margin the overflow-x scrollbar appears to allow the user to see that content, pushing the content to the left however does not have the same effect :)

Comment: I just realised that this works in chrome but not in safari for some reason.. the scrollbars are no longer appearing but the content still moves when scrolling left and right :/

Comment: Try adding either or both of these the rule: `overflow-y: auto` & `max-width: 100%`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, your explanation makes sense. I tried the CSS above though and it doesn't work unfortunately. I can remove overflow altogether by not specifying an axis, but I can't specifically remove the left to right scrolling.

Comment: In safari - any of the code above doesn't seem to stop the html or body from scrolling left or right. The scrollbars disappear but the content still moves. In chrome and opera however, it works fine. Unfortunately this seems to be the case in either the jsfiddle or my website.

Comment: Maybe there's something [**here**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20overflow-x%20safari) that can help you. Otherwise, consider posting another question targeting this specific issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look :)